# Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined at new HttpRequest

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular10

I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined at new HttpRequest (http.js:653)
> at HttpClient.request (http.js:1069)
> at HttpClient.get (http.js:1157)

when i call `get()` method from HttpClient like this:

```
this.http.get('api/link');
```

and i never has been used `indexOf` method inside my code.
What is the problem?

Comment: Can you please share more of the relevant code? Anyway the `indexOf` is used by the HttpClient module, not by you.

Comment: I think you have to provide a full path to your api `https://...`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what is the return of the API request. Sometimes it gives you back an information in the form of an array. So make sure you're using it in the same format as the request